# why my data coming from json is not being shown in the grid 

Tags: json, extjs, grid

here is my js file dashboard.js

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.QuickTips.init(); // **want to know why this is used** 

    // NOTE: This is an example showing simple state management. During development,
    // it is generally best to disable state management as dynamically-generated ids
    // can change across page loads, leading to unpredictable results.  The developer
    // should ensure that stable state ids are set for stateful components in real apps.    
    Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider());**want to know why this is used** 


    // create the data store
    var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        // store configs
        autoDestroy: true,
        autoLoad :true,
        url: 'api/index.php?_command=getresellers',
        storeId: 'getresellers',
        // reader configs
        root: 'cityarray',
        idProperty: 'cityname',
        fields: ['cityname', 'totfollowup', 'totcallback', 'totnotintrested', 'totdealsclosed', 'totcallsreceived', 'totcallsentered', 'totresellerregistered', 
            'countiro', 'irotransferred',  'irodeferred'
        ]
    });


    // create the Grid
    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store: store,
        columns: [
            {
                id       :'cityname',
                header   : 'cityname', 
                width    : 160, 
                sortable : true, 
                dataIndex: 'cityname'
            }
        ],
        stripeRows: true,
        autoExpandColumn: 'cityname',
        height: 350,
        width: 600,
        title: 'Reseller Dashboard',
        // config options for stateful behavior
        stateful: true,
        stateId: 'grid'
    });

    // render the grid to the specified div in the page
    grid.render('dashboard');
});
```

I putted some comments where i want to know why this is used ..
**want to know why this is used** 
Here is my html file

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Reseller DashBoard</title>

    <!-- ** CSS ** -->
    <!-- base library -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ext-all.css" />

    <!-- overrides to base library -->

    <!-- ** Javascript ** -->
    <!-- ExtJS library: base/adapter -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ext-base-debug.js"></script>

    <!-- ExtJS library: all widgets -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ext-all-debug.js"></script>

    <!-- overrides to base library -->

    <!-- page specific -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/dashboard.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="dashboard">



    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my json which i am also rendering in firebug ..

```
{
    "countothercities": "0",
    "directreseller": "14",
    "totalresellersregisteredfor8cities": 33,
    "cityarray": [{
        "cityname": "bangalore",
        "totfollowup": "3",
        "totcallback": "4",
        "totnotintrested": "2",
        "totdealsclosed": "0",
        "totcallsreceived": "0",
        "totcallsentered": "68",
        "totresellerregistered": "6",
        "countiro": "109",
        "irotransferred": "83",
        "irodeferred": "26"
    }, {
```

Please check .

Comment: One thing I'm definitely missing is store.load(), but that ommision is not responsible for not showing the grid.

Comment: i rectified i changed the autoExpandColumn: 'cityname',  but now my grid is rendering but data of city name is not coming ?

Comment: oops !! Okay solved problem was in the json response it is including some html tags

Comment: Your JSON is missing a closing bracket and brace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Ext.QuickTips` functionality provides attractive and customizable tooltips for any element. Have a look at this [tutorial from Sencha learning site](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Manual%3aWidgets%3aQuickTips) for details. The init method is called to initialize the singleton class of Ext.QuickTip.

The `Ext.state.Manager` is the global state manager. To make use of the state manager, you must initialize it with a provider. This is what you are doing with the statement:

```
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider());
```

Here you are using CookieProvider. By using this, you are asking the ExtJS library to store the state information of the components in cookies.

**Update**: the Error is occurring at getColumnWidth() method. check if you have proper values for the width attribute in your column model. For debugging, try removing the width detail for all the columns. I think you have more code that you have not put up here to simplify. There might be some typo.

Comment: But what about the grid rendering that is my main question ?

Comment: oh! i overlooked that.. where do you get this error? for the grid panel?

Comment: that error i rectified i changed the `autoExpandColumn: 'cityname', ` but now my grid is rendering but data of city name is not coming ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//grid.render('dashboard'); //delete this line
grid.renderTo = 'dashboard';
grid.show();
```

---

**Update**

try to remove this line

```
 autoExpandColumn: 'company'
```

Comment: done before already, i rectified i changed the autoExpandColumn: 'cityname',  but now my grid is rendering but data of city name is not coming ?

Comment: your data is not correct.. look one more time... you have 1 square bracket... you missing 'close' square bracket.. mb this is the couse?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your bug:

```
autoExpandColumn: 'company',
```

There is no column with this id.

Comment: i rectified i changed the autoExpandColumn: 'cityname',  but now my grid is rendering but data of city name is not coming ?